# making sure that my handling of utf8 is correct

Tags: perl

I am using Perl for a module that involves processing a lot of Unicode documents. I started getting nervous because I'm not opening and closing files with the utf8 layers like `open (OUT, '>:utf8', $textfile)`. However, I have been thoroughly testing and the output was still as expected. So I want to better understand why.

In a nutshell, my Perl module passes a document to an external service and gets a response. The response will be in Utf8. It uses LWP::UserAgent for this. When it gets the response it just writes it to a file:

```
my $fh;
open($fh, '>', $outputpath) or die "Could not open file '$outputpath' $!";
print $fh $response->content;
close $fh;
```

I have diffed these files against Unicode files representing the "expected" output and it is fine. And yet, you can see in my open command that I was not using the utf8 layer. So why is that?

What if I just returned $response->content to some other process, instead of printing it? Would it still be proper Unicode then?

---

I also have a separate process that I would like to ask about, very similar question. In this case I am trying to build a new service which replaces an old one. The old one read from a file like `open(my $fh, '<:utf8', $inputfile)` and wrote to a new file like `open(my $fh, '>:utf8', $outputfile)`. The new service will still read the same way, but will not write to the output file anymore. It will send the string to another server using HTTP, and on that server it will be printed to a file using `open(my $fh, '>', $outputfile)` so no utf8 layer. I can't change that code immediately.

I want the file contents to be the exact same as they would otherwise have been (none of the other processing rules are changing). Should I be nervous about losing the layer?

I think maybe it would help if I understood better what these layers are doing.

Comment: Is the `PERL_UNICODE` environment variable set? Do you have any `use open` statements in your code?

Comment: The `content` method is from [HTTP::Message](http://search.cpan.org/~oalders/HTTP-Message-6.14/lib/HTTP/Message.pm)  and "_the original raw content is returned_" by it, so you are dumping bytes to the file. (It is a general rule to always decode input and encode output though.)  As for the other question, how will you "_send the string to another server using HTTP_"?

Comment: The way it sends over HTTP is very complex, but basically it's a PSGI response. I expected that that is just byte-for-byte.

Answer (score 3):

There is no "*handling of utf8*" in the main question and that in itself isn't right.

The whole thing works, as the server *is* sending utf8 as you say, in the following way.

The `content` method used on `$response` is from [HTTP::Message](http://search.cpan.org/%7Eoalders/HTTP-Message-6.14/lib/HTTP/Message.pm)

> The content() method sets the raw content if an argument is given. If no argument is given the content is not touched. In either case the original raw content is returned.

Since you don't specify layers<sup>†</sup> in [`open`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/open.html) the default is used, likely `:unix:perlio` for Unix, with no encoding (see [PerlIO](https://perldoc.perl.org/PerlIO.html)). So you are dumping the original bytes to the disk, unchanged.

Looking further down the page, at `decoded_content( %options )`, we see the default

> `default_charset`
>
> This override the default charset guessed by content_charset() or if that fails "ISO-8859-1".

and can establish what you are getting by printing it

```
say 'Content type: ', $response->content_charset;
```

where you should get `Content type: UTF-8`.  But when you receive a different encoding from the server then *that* will wind up in the file and any code that expects utf8 will break.

One should *always decode all input and encode all output*. Then we know exactly what is going on. As input is decoded the program carries on with character strings (not bytes in whatever encoding was sent). In the end encode suitably for output. This [Effective Perler article](https://www.effectiveperlprogramming.com/2011/08/know-the-difference-between-character-strings-and-utf-8-strings/) should be useful. Here you'd use `decoded_content` and write files opened with `:encoding(UTF-8)`.

With `use open ":std", ":encoding(UTF-8)";` all I/O via standard streams in the lexical scope of this pragma will be handled as utf8. (This can be overriden for other specific uses, say by specifying layers in the three argument open.)
See [open pragma](https://perldoc.perl.org/open.html).

As for the other question, you need to properly encode what you intend to "*send to another server*."  How to do that depends on how you are "sending" it.

---

<sup>†</sup>   With [PerlIO](https://perldoc.perl.org/PerlIO.html) the I/O "layers" can be set so that encoding of input and output is done as needed behind the scenes, as data is read or written. The work is done by [Encode](https://perldoc.perl.org/Encode.html). For a nice explanation of the process see [Encode::PerlIO](http://search.cpan.org/%7Ejhi/perl-5.8.1/ext/Encode/lib/Encode/PerlIO.pod).
Also see [perlunitut](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlunitut.html), [perlunifaq](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlunifaq.html), and [perluniitro](http://perldoc.perl.org/perluniintro.html).

Comment: The main part of my question was, what is the utf8 layer actually doing. How is it changing the data on input or output?

Comment: The problem I see with decoding input and encoding output is: What if the input I am writing is already in Utf8, and then I write it using the layer 'utf8', wouldn't I double-encode and create jibberish?

Comment: @Stephen, Yes, but the correct fix isn't removing the encoding layer; it's decoding your inputs. You shouldn't be working with encoded text (e.g. text encoded using UTF-8); you should be working with decoded text (Unicode Code Points).

Comment: @Stephen  The `layers` are complex (I don't know their implementation) but in general they set encoding/decoding for affected I/O channels as specified.  Read the (whole) `open` pragma page.  // Yes, double-encoding is absolutely something to watch out for.  It'll depend on details of what your code does (for one thing, _always do both_)

Comment: @Stephen what you have now works as long as the server sends UTF-8 (which isn't something you control, or even check for). But if you use `decoded_content` plus open the output as `:encoding(UTF-8)`, it works *regardless* of what encoding the server uses (so long as it correctly advertises that in the headers, which is 99% true by now).

Comment: @Stephen but you've noticed something that's very common to "Unicode problems", which is that code that's completely wrong will often "almost" work, but fixing *part* of the problem will seem to make things much worse. You have to do *everything* right to get correct results.

Comment: _"Please recall that one should always decode all input and encode all output"_  -- I'm not sure you can make this blanket statement.  If your local character set is not UTF-8, and you decode a UTF-8 string that contains characters not in your local character set, you will lose information and will not be able to re-encode back to UTF-8.

Comment: So if I read between the lines here, it seems like the internal representation of a string in Perl will be different depending on whether it's been decoded or not? If it hasn't, it is just a byte string, but if it has, it's a string of character points?

Comment: I actually control the server that is sending this data. And it seems to be sending as UTF8 just fine, but I never set it to that. I am using a complex response with PSGI that uses a callback method to write the response (the second example here: https://metacpan.org/pod/PSGI#Delayed-Response-and-Streaming-Body). There isn't any way to set a character encoding here. YET I am writing string to it which have been decoded (so I guess they are code points) and they are being received by the recipient server as UTF8

Comment: The other thing is, I even perform a regular expression search on that raw content that I get back from $response->content to match certain parts. I'm actually only writing one of those match groups to the file, and that's what's showing up fine in diffs with the "correct" utf8 files. So it's a little strange if the raw content can't be trusted that this works for me.

Comment: @JimGarrison  I agree that most "blanket" statements aren't bullet proof. But what would one say? It's a good general rule, and then there is a matter of how to apply it. I am not sure I understand the rest. If I receive utf8 and decode it then the program will carry on with Unicode code points. Then I can encode that appropriately and send it out.

Comment: @JimGarrison `decode` doesn't care what your "local character set" is. It won't lose data. It decodes into a representation that includes everything in Unicode and then a bit more for good measure, not the system locale. *Encoding into* an encoding that lacks certain characters is a problem, but of course it is. And not a problem if you're targeting UTF-8.